# Trying to traverse a tree breadth-first but running into errors

Tags: c, tree, traversal

I am trying to traverse the tree level-order but my numbers aren't coming out level order and every other time I compile my code I get an error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

I run into the error at the printf("%d ", current->val); line in my code.

```
void printBreadthFirstTree(struct AVLTree *tree){
    struct AVLnode **queue;  
    struct AVLnode *current = tree->root;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0; 

    queue = (struct AVLnode **) malloc(100*sizeof(struct AVLnode));

    while (current)
    {
        printf("%d ", current->val);

        if (current->left){
            queue[end] = current->left;
            end++;
        }

        if (current->right){
            queue[end] = current->right;
            end++;
        }

        start++;
        current = queue[start - 1];
    }
}
```

My Tree:

```
struct AVLnode * AVLnodeAdd(struct AVLnode * current, int newValue)
{
   if(current == 0){
        struct AVLnode* node = (struct AVLnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AVLnode));
        node->val =  newValue;
        node->left = 0;
        node->right = 0;
        node->height = 1;
        return node;
    }
   else {
        if (LT(newValue, current->val))
            current->left = AVLnodeAdd(current->left, newValue);
        else {
            current->right = AVLnodeAdd(current->right, newValue);
       }
    }

    return _balance(current);
}
```

My code for balancing the tree:

```
struct AVLnode * _balance(struct AVLnode * current)
{
    int cbf = bf(current);

    if (cbf < -1) {
        int drotation = h(current->left->right) - h(current->left->left);
        if (drotation > 0){
            current->left = rotateLeft(current->left);
        }

        return rotateRight(current);

    } else if (cbf > 1) {
        int drotation = h(current->right->right) - h(current->right->left);
        if (drotation < 0) {
            current->right = rotateRight(current->right);
        }

        return rotateLeft(current);
    }

    setHeight(current);
    return current;
}
```

bf() just gets the balance factor by subtracting the height of the left node from the right.

My main code that actually adds values to this tree is run from an input file, and in main I have:

```
while((fscanf(file, "%i", &num)) != EOF){
        addAVLTree(tree, num);      
    }
```

With add AVL Tree:

```
void addAVLTree(struct AVLTree *tree, TYPE val)
{
    printf("%d ", val);
    tree->root = AVLnodeAdd(tree->root, val);   
    tree->cnt++;
}
```

I should be getting the output: 21 11 31 7 13 23 42 5 9 12 16 22 27 40 73 2 6 8 10 20 25 30 34 41 50 75 0 4 43 61 74

Instead, I get: 27 13 40 8 21 31 50 5 11 20 23 30 34 42 73 2 7 10 12 16 22 25 41 43 61 74 0 4 6 9 75 1103571808 -9075224

Comment: The `malloc` call in `printBreadthFirstTree` has the wrong argument to `sizeof`.  It should be `sizeof(struct AVLnode *)`, or `sizeof(*queue)`.  But this just means you're allocating more memory than you intended, which doesn't explain your bug.

Comment: But your queue implementation is strange, since it never wraps and instead just keeps growing in the same direction, with no check to see if you've reached the end.  The first thing I'd do is add a check to make sure `end` is less than 100 before attempting to add anything to `queue`.

Comment: Thank you @TomKarzes I will look into this!